# hover over an [li] element of a class

Tags: html, css, mediawiki

I want to hover over a navigation bar in mediawiki.

Site-Code:

```html
<div class="mw-portlet-body">
  <ul>
    <li id="n-mainpage-description">
      <a href="/index.php/Hauptseite" title="Hauptseite besuchen       [Alt+Umschalt+z]" accesskey="z">
        <span>Hauptseite</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li id="n-recentchanges">
      <a href="/index.php/Spezial:Letzte_%C3%84nderungen" title="Liste der letzten Änderungen in diesem Wiki [Alt+Umschalt+r]" accesskey="r">
        <span>Letzte Änderungen</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li id="n-randompage">
      <a href="/index.php/Spezial:Zuf%C3%A4llige_Seite" title="Zufällige Seite aufrufen [Alt+Umschalt+x]" accesskey="x">
        <span>Zufällige Seite</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li id="n-help-mediawiki">
      <a href="https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Special:MyLanguage/Help:Contents">
        <span>Help about MediaWiki</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The hover should use the class `mw-portlet-body` and the li element of the class. I don't know the scale of the project yet and want it to scale to new li elements automatically, so using the id is out of question.

I have already searched a bit and tried some CSS codes:

```
mw-portlet-body li:hover {
    background-color: rgba(242, 242, 242, 1);
}
```

or `li.mw-portlet-body:hover`

Im not sure what to do right now. I don't know/want to change the entire HTML code of the site to add classes to the lists.

I really appreciate any help, I have started with web development just recently.

Comment: you forgot the dot: `.mw-portlet-body li:hover` on the first snippet. The second one can't work because you have no `li.mw-portlet-body` elements.

Comment: jeez, i overtried it and the dot has been lost on the way. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you didn't put `.`(dot) before `mw-portlet-body`. Since it is a class you have to use `.`(dot) in css file.

```css
.mw-portlet-body li:hover {
background-color: rgba(242, 242, 242, 1);
}
```

```html
<div class="mw-portlet-body">
  <ul>
    <li id="n-mainpage-description">
      <a href="/index.php/Hauptseite" title="Hauptseite besuchen       [Alt+Umschalt+z]" accesskey="z">
        <span>Hauptseite</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li id="n-recentchanges">
      <a href="/index.php/Spezial:Letzte_%C3%84nderungen" title="Liste der letzten Änderungen in diesem Wiki [Alt+Umschalt+r]" accesskey="r">
        <span>Letzte Änderungen</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li id="n-randompage">
      <a href="/index.php/Spezial:Zuf%C3%A4llige_Seite" title="Zufällige Seite aufrufen [Alt+Umschalt+x]" accesskey="x">
        <span>Zufällige Seite</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li id="n-help-mediawiki">
      <a href="https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Special:MyLanguage/Help:Contents">
        <span>Help about MediaWiki</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

When targetting a class you need to add the `.` prefix to it. At the moment your css is targetting `<li>` elements inside `<mw-portlet-body></mw-portlet-body>` tags:

```
<mw-portlet-body>
 <li></li>
 <li></li>
</mw-portlet-body>
```

However, this isn't what you want. By adding a `.` to `mw-portlet-body` you are telling your css that `mw-portlet-body` is a class on an element and so it will select all `<li>` elements inside any element with the class `mw-portlet-body`

See working example below:

```css
.mw-portlet-body li:hover {
  background-color: rgba(242, 242, 242, 1);
}
```

```html
<div class="mw-portlet-body">
  <ul>
    <li id="n-mainpage-description">
      <a href="/index.php/Hauptseite" title="Hauptseite besuchen       [Alt+Umschalt+z]" accesskey="z">
        <span>Hauptseite</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li id="n-recentchanges">
      <a href="/index.php/Spezial:Letzte_%C3%84nderungen" title="Liste der letzten Änderungen in diesem Wiki [Alt+Umschalt+r]" accesskey="r">
        <span>Letzte Änderungen</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li id="n-randompage">
      <a href="/index.php/Spezial:Zuf%C3%A4llige_Seite" title="Zufällige Seite aufrufen [Alt+Umschalt+x]" accesskey="x">
        <span>Zufällige Seite</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li id="n-help-mediawiki">
      <a href="https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Special:MyLanguage/Help:Contents">
        <span>Help about MediaWiki</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you need to do is to add a dot to refer class (e.g. `.mw-portlet-body li` instead of `mw-portlet-body li`)